# Подходящий эквивалент в русском языке для английского 'XOXO'?

Tags: лексика, выбор-слов, переводы

Есть [некоторые затруднения](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4720/213987) с переводом строк со страницы входа на сайт Stack Exchange:
[image: XOX]

С одной стороны, всегда можно заменить на нейтральное "С уважением, команда Stack Exchange", но можно попробовать найти и какой-то более точный перевод без оттенка фамильярности ("Чмоки, команда Stack Exchange").

Есть какие-нибудь идеи?

Для справки: [XOXO в Urban dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=xoxo)

Answer (score 3):

В русском нет аббревиатур такого назначения (разве что "ХВ" на Пасху): если подходящее стандартное выражение ("всегда с вами" или "берегите себя" - в зависимости от повода) сократить, никто не поймёт. В лучшем случае можно завести такую условность в отдельном форуме, включив её в общие правила для участников. Копирование же английских аббревиатур кириллицей (вместо прямого воспроизведения известных LOL и пр. - здесь это не проходит, поскольку наводит на мысль об Эллочке-людоедке) обычно производит впечатление дурного вкуса (как с распространившимся "ИМХО") или небрежной невежливости ("ЗЫ" - мол, не буду ради вас раскладку переключать). Поэтому лучше пользоваться полным русским штампом, выглядящим уместно в конкретной ситуации, и не привязываться к данному изыску.

Answer (score 0):

Пусть уж англичане рулят. Полновесный русский эквивалент звучит ещё фамильярнее -

ЦЕ-НА-КРЫЛЬЦЕ!

Можно попробовать "Вы тоже отлично выглядите"...